# Yii 2 custom class not found

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to add a custom class to my Yii2 application, so I created a folder called "**Payment**" and inside this folder I created a class called Test.php, and the namespace is "payment"

```
 <?php
     namespace payment;
     class Test{
          public static function test(){
            echo "Hello";
          }
      }
```

in my controller I add this

```
use payment;
```

and I am trying to access the method in the test class but I got class not found fatal error.
what is wrong?
Structure:
+ project-name-folder:
     -api
         -Payment
            -Test.php
         -modules
            - v1
                - controllers
                      - HelloController.php

Comment: Basic or advanced template?

Comment: advanced, the classes I am trying to inside API module

Comment: It's most likely because you're using incorrect path or defined wrong namespace path. Can you give me exactly where did you create that `payment` folder?

Comment: projectname -> api -> Payment

Comment: That `api` is in frontend, backend or common folder? Or none of these? If none, you may need to put inside of these then first.

Comment: api is none of thses, but why api module is not seen? since its like backend and frontend?

Comment: Maybe not required but recommended at least.

Comment: I move the folder to backend folder and i changed the namespace and it works, thank you.

Comment: It wasn't me who wrote that answer but still glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is basic project template all classes should be under root namespace `app`.
If this is advanced project template classes should be under root namespace based on the application they are in so `frontend`, `common`, or `backend`.

Your class namespace should be changed like:

```
namespace <root>\payment;
```

where `<root>` is `app`, `frontend`, `common`, or `backend`. Every `use` of this class should be modified accordingly.